# want to sum time (00:00:00) in AWK command

Tags: awk

I have awk command to sum time from another filed it works with the numbers, but when tried with hours it doesn't work

example

```
> cat ee.txt
amazon|4
ebay|5
alibab|10
ebay|4
amazon|5

> awk -F '|' '$1 ~ /ebay/{ sum += $2 } END{ print sum }' ee.txt
8
```

but when I need to sum the time the command doesnt work

```
> cat ee.txt
amazon  1:02:00
ebay    2:00:00
alibab  240:00:00
ebay    3:00:00
amazon  72:00:00

> awk -F '|' '$1 ~ /ebay/{ sum += $2 } END{ print sum }' ee.txt
```

the output should be 5:00:00

Comment: 4+5=8? Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: Dear Cryus , I am new here , but I already put both examples there

Comment: amad@amad-VirtualBox:~$ cat e1.txt 
amazon|1
ebay|2
alibab|3
ebay|1
amazon|5
amad@amad-VirtualBox:~$ cat e2.txt 
amazon|1:02:00
ebay|2:50:00
alibab|240:00:00
ebay|3:04:00
amazon|72:00:00
amad@amad-VirtualBox:~$ awk -F '|' '$1 =="ebay" { sum += $2 } END{ print sum }' e1.txt
3
amad@amad-VirtualBox:~$ awk -F '|' '$1 =="ebay" { sum += $2 } END{ print sum }' e2.txt
5
amad@amad-VirtualBox:~$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this maybe:

```
$ awk '
/ebay/ {
    split($2,a,":")                # separate hs, ms and sses
    b+=a[1]*3600+a[2]*60+a[3]      # sum them up as as seconds
}
END {
    h=int(b/3600)                  # separate hs
    m=int((b-3600*h)/60)           # and ms
    s=b-3600*h-60*m                # and sses
    printf "%d:%02d:%02d\n",h,m,s  # output
}' file
5:00:00
```

Basically you need to convert all time components to seconds, sum the records up and break them up to components again. You could also use [GNU awk's time functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Time-Functions.html) but that wouldn't allow all hh:mm:ss output, as times > 24 h would convert to dates.

**Edit**:

Added a version for all summing upp all values and grouping by company name:

```
$ awk '
{
    split($2,a,":")                         # separate hs, ms and sses
    b[$1]+=a[1]*3600+a[2]*60+a[3]           # sum them up as as seconds
}
END { 
    for(i in b) {
        h=int(b[i]/3600)                    # separate hs
        m=int((b[i]-3600*h)/60)             # and ms
        s=b[i]-3600*h-60*m                  # and sses
        printf "%s %d:%02d:%02d\n",i,h,m,s  # output
    }
}' file
alibab 240:00:00
amazon 73:02:00
ebay 5:00:00
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your prompt reply but when i run i faced below error awk: line 1: syntax error at or near +=
awk: line 1: extra ')'
awk: line 1: extra ')'
awk: line 1: syntax error at or near =

Comment: Reload the page and cut'n paste the script again. There was a bug earlier.

Comment: thanks James , I removed the value 24:00:00 after run your command the result is 0:00:00 I dont know what is wrong

Comment: There was no value 24:00:00 in your sample.

Comment: Dear James thanks a lot , I have solved the issue with below command appreciate it    awk -F '|' '$1 =="KRK" {
    split($2,a,":")                # separate hs, ms and sses
    b+=a[1]*3600+a[2]*60+a[3]      # sum them up as as seconds
}
END {
    h=int(b/3600)                  # separate hs
    m=int((b-3600*h)/60)           # and ms
    s=b-3600*h-60*m                # and sses
    printf "%d:%02d:%02d\n",h,m,s  # output
}' fiber1.txt
3:38:00

Comment: Also, I can't help with what I can't see. Therefore the sample in the question is extremely valuable. Different values for different companies then you can say "I removed the 24:00:00 from company1 and the result was 0:00:00".

Comment: James would you please tell me how is (printf "%d:%02d:%02d\n",h,m,s ) working what is meaning of %d or %2d?

Comment: `%d` for printing digits, `%02` prints zeropadded digits, ie. `1` -> `01` but `10` -> `10`. `%03d` would produce `10` -> `010` etc.

Comment: thanks a lot dear I am new here , how can i vote increase your points or I want to reward you with money , please let me know how can I chat you ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186268/discussion-between-amad2018-and-james-brown).

Comment: Hello James ,please tell me how can I print each value and its total time like ebay|5:00:00 ,amazon|73:02:00 and so on

Comment: Updated with a version. Next time make another question and link this answer to it. That way you get the answer most likely faster,

Answer (score 0):

Another awk using space and : as delimiter

```
$ awk -F"[ :]+" ' { a[$1]+=$2*3600+$3*60+$4 } END {for(i in a){hr=int(a[i]/3600);mi=int((a[i]-hr*3600)/60);s=a[i]-3600*hr-60*mi;printf("%s %02d:%02d:%02d\n", i,hr,mi,s) }}' ee.txt
ebay 05:00:00
alibab 240:00:00
amazon 73:02:00
```